# Kubernetes ClusterIP not balancing load across Pods

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I am having an issue with load balancing of traffic between communicating Deployment resources deployed in Kubernetes.

Namely the Deployment A communicates to Deployment B via vanilla ClusterIP type Service. When Deployment A starts causing large load on Deployment B, the Deployment B starts scaling new pods, but when new Pods become ready, they get no traffic.

What seems to be happening is that ClusterIP Service is balancing incoming connections instead of incoming requests, so that only pods which were available before scale-up are under load.

My question is then:

How to make ClusterIP balance the incoming requests across Pods, instead of balancing incoming TCP connections? In case that such thing is not possible, what is the alternative for balancing the HTTP traffic between two deployments?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your setup, such as whether you have a networking fabric in use and which CNI, no can can help you. I can assure you that a "vanilla" ClusterIP does not behave as you are describing, which is why you have to provide more debugging details

Comment: I am using default configured  EKS cluster. What info would be necessary in order to be able to answer the question?